# Print range of files based on time range using awk?

Tags: awk, time

I have done a few simple things with `awk` but I cannot find a way to do this!  I have a text file containing entries named with year, julian date and time as such:

```
blah_2012251_130500_blah  
blah_2012251_131000_blah  
blah_2012251_131500_blah  
...  
blah_2012253_063000_blah
```

and I am trying to find a way to create a new file with entries within a specific time range only.  For example, year 2012 and day 251 at 2:02pm (140200) to 2012 day 252 to at 6:07am (060700) should contain files to span the times:

```
blah_2012251_140000_blah  
blah_2012251_140500_blah
...  
blah_2012252_060500_blah
blah_2012252_061000_blah
```

Also, the files do not always increment every 5 minutes like in this example, so it needs to be an open range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following should work..adjust field ordinals 2 and 3 as needed

```
 awk -F'_' 'int($2""$3) > 2012252140600 && int($2""$3) < 2012252180700' filename
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  This way is very simple and works great!  I'm sorry I wasn't clear before but I also need to include the 1 file BEFORE the starting time in the case that the starting time does not match the file name exactly.  Meaning, for time 140600, if there is not a file called 140600 I need the file before it, could be 140500 or in some cases even 135900.

Answer (score 1):

f1 and f2 are the starting date and time, l1 and l2 are the ending date and time:

```
awk -F_  -v f1="2012251" -v f2="140200" -v l1="2012252" -v l2="060700" '($2==f1 && $3>=f2) || ($2==l1 && $3<=l2) || ($2>f1 && $2<l1)' file
```

Comment: Thank you! I probably wasn't clear before but I also need the file before 140200 which is file 140000 (and in some cases could be file 135900, for example).